# How I can extract the text in the blurb below?

Tags: python, text, rtf

Any suggestions on how I can extract the text in the blurb below? It's from a SQL database. This is just 1 field from a csv export.
I just need the text starting from Column 14457 to 14528 where it says ***HelloWorld, HelloWorld, HelloWorld. HelloWorld, HelloWorld, HelloWorld!*** It's close to the bottom.

```
~~~Text starts here
{\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\adeff0\deff0\stshfdbch31505\stshfloch31506\stshfhich31506\stshfbi31507\deflang1033\deflangfe1033\themelang1033\themelangfe0\themelangcs0{\fonttbl{\f0\fbidi \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\f1\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 020b0604020202020204}Arial;}  {\f2\fbidi \fmodern\fcharset0\fprq1{\*\panose 02070309020205020404}Courier New;}{\f5\fbidi \fmodern\fcharset0\fprq1{\*\panose 02070409020205020404}Courier;}  {\flomajor\f31500\fbidi \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\fdbmajor\f31501\fbidi \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}  {\fhimajor\f31502\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 020f0302020204030204}Calibri Light;}{\fbimajor\f31503\fbidi \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}  {\flominor\f31504\fbidi \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\fdbminor\f31505\fbidi \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}  {\fhiminor\f31506\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 020f0502020204030204}Calibri;}{\fbiminor\f31507\fbidi \froman\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}            {\flomajor\f31508\fbidi \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times New Roman CE;}  {\flomajor\f31509\fbidi \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times New Roman Cyr;}{\flomajor\f31511\fbidi \froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Times New Roman Greek;}{\flomajor\f31512\fbidi \froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Times New Roman Tur;}  {\flomajor\f31513\fbidi \froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman (Hebrew);}{\flomajor\f31514\fbidi \froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New Roman (Arabic);}{\flomajor\f31515\fbidi \froman\fcharset186\fprq2 Times New Roman Baltic;}  {\flomajor\f31516\fbidi \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}{\fdbmajor\f31518\fbidi \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times New Roman CE;}{\fdbmajor\f31519\fbidi \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times New Roman Cyr;}  {\fdbmajor\f31521\fbidi \froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Times New Roman Greek;}{\fdbmajor\f31522\fbidi \froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Times New Roman Tur;}{\fdbmajor\f31523\fbidi \froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman (Hebrew);}  {\fdbmajor\f31524\fbidi \froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New Roman (Arabic);}{\fdbmajor\f31525\fbidi \froman\fcharset186\fprq2 Times New Roman Baltic;}{\fdbmajor\f31526\fbidi \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}  {\fhimajor\f31528\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset238\fprq2 Calibri Light CE;}{\fhimajor\f31529\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset204\fprq2 Calibri Light Cyr;}{\fhimajor\f31531\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset161\fprq2 Calibri Light Greek;}  {\fhimajor\f31532\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset162\fprq2 Calibri Light Tur;}{\fhimajor\f31535\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset186\fprq2 Calibri Light Baltic;}{\fhimajor\f31536\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset163\fprq2 Calibri Light (Vietnamese);}  {\fbimajor\f31538\fbidi \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times New Roman CE;}{\fbimajor\f31539\fbidi \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times New Roman Cyr;}{\fbimajor\f31541\fbidi \froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Times New Roman Greek;}  {\fbimajor\f31542\fbidi \froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Times New Roman Tur;}{\fbimajor\f31543\fbidi \froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman (Hebrew);}{\fbimajor\f31544\fbidi \froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New Roman (Arabic);}  {\fbimajor\f31545\fbidi \froman\fcharset186\fprq2 Times New Roman Baltic;}{\fbimajor\f31546\fbidi \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}{\flominor\f31548\fbidi \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times New Roman CE;}  {\flominor\f31549\fbidi \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times New Roman Cyr;}{\flominor\f31551\fbidi \froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Times New Roman Greek;}{\flominor\f31552\fbidi \froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Times New Roman Tur;}  {\flominor\f31553\fbidi \froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman (Hebrew);}{\flominor\f31554\fbidi \froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New Roman (Arabic);}{\flominor\f31555\fbidi \froman\fcharset186\fprq2 Times New Roman Baltic;}  {\flominor\f31556\fbidi \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}{\fdbminor\f31558\fbidi \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times New Roman CE;}{\fdbminor\f31559\fbidi \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times New Roman Cyr;}  {\fdbminor\f31561\fbidi \froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Times New Roman Greek;}{\fdbminor\f31562\fbidi \froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Times New Roman Tur;}{\fdbminor\f31563\fbidi \froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman (Hebrew);}  {\fdbminor\f31564\fbidi \froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New Roman (Arabic);}{\fdbminor\f31565\fbidi \froman\fcharset186\fprq2 Times New Roman Baltic;}{\fdbminor\f31566\fbidi \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}  {\fhiminor\f31568\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset238\fprq2 Calibri CE;}{\fhiminor\f31569\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset204\fprq2 Calibri Cyr;}{\fhiminor\f31571\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset161\fprq2 Calibri Greek;}{\fhiminor\f31572\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset162\fprq2 Calibri Tur;}  {\fhiminor\f31575\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset186\fprq2 Calibri Baltic;}{\fhiminor\f31576\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset163\fprq2 Calibri (Vietnamese);}{\fbiminor\f31578\fbidi \froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times New Roman CE;}  {\fbiminor\f31579\fbidi \froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times New Roman Cyr;}{\fbiminor\f31581\fbidi \froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Times New Roman Greek;}{\fbiminor\f31582\fbidi \froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Times New Roman Tur;}  {\fbiminor\f31583\fbidi \froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman (Hebrew);}{\fbiminor\f31584\fbidi \froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New Roman (Arabic);}{\fbiminor\f31585\fbidi \froman\fcharset186\fprq2 Times New Roman Baltic;}  {\fbiminor\f31586\fbidi \froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}}{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;\red0\green255\blue255;\red0\green255\blue0;\red255\green0\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue0;  \red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue128;\red0\green128\blue128;\red0\green128\blue0;\red128\green0\blue128;\red128\green0\blue0;\red128\green128\blue0;\red128\green128\blue128;\red192\green192\blue192;}{\*\defchp   \fs22\loch\af31506\hich\af31506\dbch\af31505 }{\*\defpap \ql \li0\ri0\sa160\sl259\slmult1\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 }\noqfpromote {\stylesheet{  \ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \snext0 \sqformat \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 Normal;}{\*\cs10   \additive \ssemihidden \sunhideused \spriority1 \styrsid2753133 Default Paragraph Font;}{\*  \ts11\tsrowd\trftsWidthB3\trpaddl108\trpaddr108\trpaddfl3\trpaddft3\trpaddfb3\trpaddfr3\trcbpat1\trcfpat1\tblind0\tblindtype3\tsvertalt\tsbrdrt\tsbrdrl\tsbrdrb\tsbrdrr\tsbrdrdgl\tsbrdrdgr\tsbrdrh\tsbrdrv \ql \li0\ri0\sa160\sl259\slmult1  \widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af31507\afs22\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\loch\f31506\hich\af31506\dbch\af31505\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \snext11 \ssemihidden \sunhideused   Normal Table;}{\s15\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\tx9360\tx10080\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0   \f1\fs18\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \snext15 \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 AppName Text;}{\s16\ql \li0\ri0\nowidctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0   \b\fs24\cf2\lang1033\langfe1033\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon0 \snext16 \sautoupd \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 AppName Title;}{\s17\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025   \ltrch\fcs0 \f2\fs20\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon0 \snext17 \slink18 \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 Plain Text;}{\*\cs18 \additive \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f2\fs20   \sbasedon10 \slink17 \slocked \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 Plain Text Char;}{\s19\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\tx4500\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0   \f1\fs18\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon29 \snext19 \sautoupd \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 Default Quick Text Style;}{\s20\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar  \tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\tx9360\tx10080\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0   \f1\fs24\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon15 \snext20 \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 Arial 12 Point;}{\s21\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar  \tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\tx9360\tx10080\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0   \f1\fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon17 \snext21 \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 Arial 11 Point;}{\s22\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar  \tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\tx9360\tx10080\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0   \f1\fs20\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon15 \snext22 \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 Arial 10 Point;}{\s23\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar  \tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\tx9360\tx10080\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0   \f1\fs28\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon15 \snext23 \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 Arial 14 Point;}{\s24\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar  \tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\tx9360\tx10080\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0   \fs18\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon15 \snext24 \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 Times New Roman 9 Point;}{\s25\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar  \tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\tx9360\tx10080\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0   \fs20\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon15 \snext25 \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 Times New Roman 10 Point;}{\s26\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar  \tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\tx9360\tx10080\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0   \fs22\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon15 \snext26 \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 Times New Roman 11 Point;}{\s27\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar  \tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\tx9360\tx10080\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0   \fs24\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon15 \snext27 \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 Times New Roman 12 Point;}{\s28\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar  \tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\tx9360\tx10080\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0   \fs28\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon15 \snext28 \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 Times New Roman 14 Point;}{\s29\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025   \ltrch\fcs0 \f1\fs18\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon0 \snext29 \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 Arial;}{\s30\ql \li0\ri0\sl-240\slmult0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1   \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \f5\fs20\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 \sbasedon17 \snext30 \spriority0 \styrsid2753133 RSP Print;}}{\*\rsidtbl \rsid1117378\rsid1986564\rsid2753133}{\mmathPr\mmathFont34\mbrkBin0\mbrkBinSub0  \msmallFrac0\mdispDef1\mlMargin0\mrMargin0\mdefJc1\mwrapIndent1440\mintLim0\mnaryLim1}{\info{\operator FN LN}{\creatim\yr2023\mo12\dy27\hr9\min35}{\revtim\yr2023\mo12\dy27\hr9\min39}{\version3}{\edmins4}{\nofpages1}{\nofwords10}{\nofchars62}  {\nofcharsws71}{\vern109}}{\*\xmlnstbl {\xmlns1 http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml}}\paperw12240\paperh15840\margl1080\margr720\margt360\margb360\gutter0\ltrsect   \widowctrl\ftnbj\aenddoc\trackmoves0\trackformatting1\donotembedsysfont0\relyonvml0\donotembedlingdata1\grfdocevents0\validatexml0\showplaceholdtext0\ignoremixedcontent0\saveinvalidxml0\showxmlerrors0\horzdoc\dghspace120\dgvspace120\dghorigin1701  \dgvorigin1984\dghshow0\dgvshow3\jcompress\viewkind1\viewscale108\rsidroot2753133 \fet0{\*\wgrffmtfilter 2450}\ilfomacatclnup0{\*\template C:\\XY\\test\\word_fls\\QuickTxt.dotm}{\*\docvar {ContainerApp}{AppName\'ae (TEST)}}  {\*\docvar {IniFile}{C:\'5cXY\'5cTEMP\'5csession8\'5ctsmi5j0d\'5c140700\'5cqt_coword.ini}}{\*\docvar {ParentHandle}{140700}}{\*\docvar {TemplateDirectory}{C:\'5cXY\'5cptest\'5cword_fls\'5c}}\ltrpar \sectd \ltrsect\linex0\sectdefaultcl\sftnbj {\*\pnseclvl1  \pnucrm\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta .}}{\*\pnseclvl2\pnucltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta .}}{\*\pnseclvl3\pndec\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta .}}{\*\pnseclvl4\pnlcltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta )}}{\*\pnseclvl5  \pndec\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}{\*\pnseclvl6\pnlcltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}{\*\pnseclvl7\pnlcrm\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}{\*\pnseclvl8\pnlcltr\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang   {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}{\*\pnseclvl9\pnlcrm\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}\pard\plain \ltrpar\s15\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\tx720\tx1440\tx2160\tx2880\tx3600\tx4320\tx5040\tx5760\tx6480\tx7200\tx7920\tx8640\tx9360\tx10080\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0\pararsid2753133 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \f1\fs18\lang1033\langfe1033\cgrid\langnp1033\langfenp1033 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid1117378 HelloWorld, HelloWorld, HelloWorld. HelloWorld, HelloWorld, HelloWorld!}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \insrsid1986564 \par }{\*\noop}{\*\noop}{\*\noop}{\*\noop}}
~~~Text ends here
```

I've tried making a python program with not luck.

Comment: python would be great. Thanks.

Comment: pypandoc may be helpful, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/77693269/80901

Answer (score 2):

Use [`striprtf`](https://pypi.org/project/striprtf/):

```py
from striprtf.striprtf import rtf_to_text

txt = r"""{\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi (...) {\*\noop}}"""
>>> rtf_to_text(txt).strip()
'HelloWorld, HelloWorld, HelloWorld. HelloWorld, HelloWorld, HelloWorld!'
```

Comment: While this solution works, it is for PHP and does not use Python.